# Java pattern first letter should not be hyphens (-), apostrophes (‘), and spaces ( )

Tags: java, regex

I am using this pattern to check

```
public static final Pattern VALID_FIRST_CHARACTERS = Pattern.compile("^[\\ \\'\\-]");

public boolean isValidFirstChar(String name) {
    if (VALID_FIRST_CHARACTERS.matcher(name).matches()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

no luck, can somebody help me please ?

Comment: What do you think the pattern literal `^[\\ \\'\\-]` represents? Why do you think so?

Comment: Also why aren't you using `String#startsWith`?

Comment: I am using     public static final Pattern VALID_NAMEFIELD_CHARACTERS = Pattern
   .compile("([a-zA-Z àâäèéêëîïôœùûüÿçÀÂÄÈÉÊËÎÏÔŒÙÛÜŸÇ\\ \\'\\-])*");

and it is working fine 
just not able check the first character

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I need to do all 3 validation at one time 
if I use string start with I have to use 3 time

Comment: Why do you _have to_? Do you think it's faster, more efficient? Why do you think so?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis because I need it

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis he doesn't `"Why do you have to?"` have to use regex but the code is cleaner if he does...I don't think it has anything to do with being faster or more efficient just cleaner looking code. Better readability...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change yours like this and it will work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    System.out.println(isValidFirstChar("-test"));
    System.out.println(isValidFirstChar("\\test"));
    System.out.println(isValidFirstChar("\'test"));
    System.out.println(isValidFirstChar("test"));
}
public static final Pattern VALID_FIRST_CHARACTERS = Pattern.compile("^[\\\\ \\' \\-].*");

public static boolean isValidFirstChar(String name) {
    if (VALID_FIRST_CHARACTERS.matcher(name).matches()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The result of this is:

```
true
true
true
false
```

You must escape the `\\` for java but also for regex that is why you need `\\\\` this will become `\\` when translated for the regex...

The `.*` on the end means match anything after...So it starts with `\ or ' or -` and is followed by anything.

Comment: thanks for your reply 
its working
I just needed hyphens (-), apostrophes (‘), and spaces ( ) to be matched 
so I changed it to 
    public static final Pattern VALID_FIRST_CHARACTERS = Pattern
   .compile("^[' -].*");
working fine now 
thanks 
@brso05